# Multiple paragraphs in single form field - Jquery append on keydown

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a very basic CMS that I've put together with PHP and MySQL. Everything works great, except I can't find a way to make textarea fields capable of containing multiple paragraphs (e.g. blog posts, detailed service descriptions). The data is stored in MySQL with `<br>`s between the paragraphs, but when I call it back for display, all breaks are removed. There is nothing in the PHP that would pull out html (no trimming of html entities, string replacing, etc.) Ideally, I'd be able to wrap the cursor in `<p></p>` like this textarea I'm typing in now does.

Today I've been trying JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#thetest').keydown(function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    $('#thetest').append('<p>Test</p>');
});
});
</script>

<form action="test_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<p>Content: </p>
<textarea wrap="virtual" id="thetest" name="thetest" value="" 
autocomplete="off" rows="20"cols="100">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'd think there'd be a jquery plugin for forms that would handle it, but I haven't found one. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Could you use TinyMCE? http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: Textareas can only hold plain text with `\n` as newline. Use TinyMCE like @captainclam suggested, or struggle with the caveats of contenteditable yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are your users typing in the paragraph tags, or do you want it WYSIWYG style? If it's the former, you shouldn't have a problem (and if you do, you can just htmlentities() it before it goes in and decode when you fetch it). If it's the latter, I would process the $_POST['thetest'] string as it comes back to you before putting it in your database. You can preg_replace() your newline characters with `<p>` and `</p>` before storing it, with more newline characters to make it readable of course.

Or you can cheat with `<pre>` just to preserve white space, but that wouldn't be semantically responsible :p

Comment: My users aren't typing any tags and I'm looking WYSIWYG. Since posting the original question, I've started using the CKEditor Jquery plugin and it works, but I would like to know how to perform this task for my own programming edification. I tried preg_replace() on newline characters but the newline characters weren't showing up. Is it impractical to go through the trouble of appending on keydown with jquery?

Comment: The code that I provided in my answer should do as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `nl2br(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($paragraphs)))`, it will output the text exactly how the user inputs it.